# Can't perform polymorphic deserialization of nested collections using Moshi PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory

Tags: java, json, moshi

Complex nested Data types won't deserialize to intended classes using a standard approach.

As of now, I have this working code, which deserializes json to `Map<String, ? extends T>` structure:

```
    private static <T> Map<String, ? extends T> deserializeTypeAdaptableJson(Class<T> baseType, List<Class<? extends T>> subclasses, String json) {
        PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory<T> factory = PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(baseType, "type");
        for (Class<? extends T> subclass : subclasses) {
            factory = factory.withSubtype(subclass, subclass.getSimpleName());
        }
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().add(factory).build();
        ParameterizedType type = Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, String.class, baseType);
        JsonAdapter<Map<String, ? extends T>> adapter = moshi.adapter(type);
        return adapter.fromJson(json);
```

What I actually need to deserialize is  `Map<String, List<? extends T>>`, but this code

```
    private static <T> Map<String, List<? extends T>> deserializeTypeAdaptableJson(Class<T> baseType, List<Class<? extends T>> subclasses, String json) {
        PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory<T> factory = PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(baseType, "type");
        for (Class<? extends T> subclass : subclasses) {
            factory = factory.withSubtype(subclass, subclass.getSimpleName());
        }
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().add(factory).build();
        ParameterizedType type = Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, String.class, List.class, baseType);
        JsonAdapter<Map<String, List<? extends T>>> adapter = moshi.adapter(type);
        return adapter.fromJson(json);
```

however gives me the correct structure - `Map` with `String` keys and `List` values, but inside of those lists instead of subclasses' instances, I receive Gson's `LinkedHashTreeMap` with "type" property storing the actual class.
I couldn't find an example for deserializing nested collections. What do I need to add?

Comment: What do you mean by "won't deserialize" and "won't work"? Any excpetion messages?

Comment: If you post runnable code with your expected result and your actual result and tag me, I'll take a look.

Comment: @kerbermeister added more context - structure (Map<String, List<>>) I get is okay, the problem is in List's elements - they are not deserialized to target classes polymorphically, but to LinkedHashTreeMap's. No exceptions or errors, just wrong types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that to deserialize nested collections we have to pass nested parametrized types to the adapter.
After changing this

```
ParameterizedType type = Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, String.class, List.class, baseType);
```

```
ParameterizedType type = Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, String.class, Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, baseType));
```

I now have a working solution - I get a `Map` with `List<? extends T>` values, where values are actual descendants of a common ancestor and not `LinkedHashTreeMap`s.